# SQL skip is value is null

Tags: sql

I have this SQL:

```js
SELECT
  JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.name') AS name,
  JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.total') AS total,
FROM `somewhere`
```

It produces data such as:

```
Leon   null 
Ashlee 38
Peter  null
```

I want to only return records where `total` is not null. What do I need to adjust in my query? I know it's probably a `WHERE`, but I never work with SQL so not sure what.

Comment: _"where total is not null"_  did you try this or something like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it in [where](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause
and [IS NOT NULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp) filter

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.name') AS name,
  JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.total') AS total,
FROM `somewhere`
WHERE
     JSON_VALUE(DATA, '$.name') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. That works! I thought I'll get some dislikes here for asking ¯\_(ツ)_/¯